# Conda fails to install the Anaconda distribution with Python 3.7

Tags: python, conda

I am trying to install a complete Python 3.7 environment with the full Anaconda distribution, using the following `environment.yml` file:

```
name: py37
channels:
  - anaconda
  - conda-forge
  - default
dependencies:
  - anaconda
  - python=3.7
```

using `conda env create --file environment.yml`.

Upon completion only the following packages are installed:

```
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
anaconda                  custom                   py37_0    anaconda
ca-certificates           2018.03.07                    0    anaconda
certifi                   2018.8.24                py37_1    anaconda
libcxx                    4.0.1                h579ed51_0    anaconda
libcxxabi                 4.0.1                hebd6815_0    anaconda
libedit                   3.1.20170329         hb402a30_2    anaconda
libffi                    3.2.1                h475c297_4    anaconda
ncurses                   6.1                  h0a44026_0    anaconda
openssl                   1.0.2p               h1de35cc_0    anaconda
pip                       10.0.1                   py37_0    anaconda
python                    3.7.0                hc167b69_0    anaconda
readline                  7.0                  h1de35cc_5    anaconda
setuptools                40.2.0                   py37_0    anaconda
sqlite                    3.24.0               ha441bb4_0    anaconda
tk                        8.6.8                ha441bb4_0    anaconda
wheel                     0.31.1                   py37_0    anaconda
xz                        5.2.4                h1de35cc_4    anaconda
zlib                      1.2.11               hf3cbc9b_2    anaconda
```

I am expecting `numpy`, `scipy`, etc. What's happening?

Comment: I can't see `numpy` and `scipy` packages in your `environment.yml`

Comment: `anaconda` as a package has that built-in I think

Comment: @Usernamenotfound Indeed, but the 'anaconda' package that shows up there is just a meta-package reference apparently. For a clean python 3.6 install, the whole list will appear.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar As far as I understand that's the whole point. Anaconda is a meta-package and will install a complete set of packages.

Comment: If you want to create an environment with anaconda meta-package you don't need  `environment.yml`. You can try `conda create --name env1` where env1 is your environment name.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar Doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @CedricH. Most likely, not all of the packages that are specified in the `anaconda` meta package are available for Python 3.7. You'll have to wait until a new version of Anaconda is released, I suppose

Comment: @darthbith Thanks, after looking around a lot that's also my conclusion.However I found this: https://www.anaconda.com/blog/developer-blog/python-3-7-package-build-out-miniconda-release/ which seems to imply that the whole thing is ready.

Comment: I guess they haven't "tagged" a new release of the `anaconda` package with Python 3.7 yet, hence the `custom` version in the list there.

Comment: @darthbith Do you know the exact meaning of custom for conda?

Comment: Despite many many attemps at solving this I am still blocked... the environment in the OP seems trivial/simple enough that it should work.

Comment: `custom` means that it is not one of the tagged Anaconda releases, I suppose. I'm not an employee of Anaconda, Inc. though, so I can't be sure.